# Add authentification on a Flexdashboard Rmarkdown

Tags: authentication, flexdashboard

We've developped an interactive app with Flexdashboard hosted on our own Linux server.
Is there a way to quickly implement an authentification service to it ?
We've had a look on Polished, but requests a server.r and ui.r and a global.r files.
Because it's Flexdashboard we do not have those files;

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for posting this question because it inspired me to look into whether or not it would be possible to use polished with flexdashboard.  I was not sure if it would work at first, but it turns out that it does!

The code for a working demo of using polished with flexdashboard is here: https://github.com/Tychobra/polished_example_apps/tree/master/05_flex_dashboard

And I deployed a live app here: https://tychobra.shinyapps.io/05_flex_dashboard/. You can sign in using username: demo@tychobra.com and password: polished

I set up polished with that demo flexdashboard using the new polished.tech API which makes it so you do not need to set up and maintain your own PostgreSQL database.  You can learn more about using the polished.tech API with polished here: https://polished.tech/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. We've finally decided to move to a more classical shiny app using dashboard for 2 reasons. First, it appears that flexdashboard (which is very cool) could lead to a heavy loading process. As cool as it is, and easy to implement, it was not adpated to our purpose since the app includes many charts (maps, table, graphs)and with flexdashboard it appears that all the charts are loaded at the same time versus a shiny dashboard, charts are loaded along the navigation. And second reason "WAS" the polished issue, but now with your post, it's no longer the case.

Comment: @Andy Merlino `secure_static` does not work to `flexdashboard` dynamic page (with `render` functions, like `renderValueBox`). Is there any solution for this?

Comment: We just updated polished so that you can now use runtime shiny with polished authentication.  Docs are here: https://polished.tech/docs/rmarkdown-auth and links to a live example app and code can be found here: https://polished.tech/examples#09_rmarkdown